# What values do you return from an ArrayList if the method returns an Enumeration?

Tags: java, arraylist, vector, enumeration

So I am currently upgrading some old code which uses `Vector` into `ArrayList` and am unsure what to use to replace the old vector segment.

```
public Enumeration enumerateMapping() {
    return mappingList.elements();
}
```

I need to replace the `.elements()` with an `ArrayList` equivalent. If anyone happens to know of a link with the translation for these that would be very helpful as well.

Comment: mappingList is a Vector type, by the way.

Comment: Don't comment on your own question to add information; instead [edit] your question to make it better.

Comment: You need to change method signature itself. You cannot replace `.elements()` with `ArrayList` equivalent with out changing return value

Comment: `return Collections.enumeration(mappingList);`You should also give your Enumeration a generic type.

Comment: You might consider using the Java 5 "for each" loop, rather than an Enumerator.... [Oracle's site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` (and most `Collection`s) implement `Iterable`, so you should return `iterator()` :

```
public Iterator enumerateMapping() {
    return mappingList.iterator();
}
```

It would be better to use the generic type instead of the raw type, i.e. `Iterator<ElementType>`.

As the `Enumeration` Javadoc suggests, it is recommended to use `Iterator` instead of `Enumeration` :

> NOTE: The functionality of this interface is duplicated by the Iterator interface. In addition, Iterator adds an optional remove operation, and has shorter method names. New implementations should consider using Iterator in preference to Enumeration.